# Protect specified cell in google Sheet with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this :

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var protection = sh.protect().setDescription('BVDATA');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges([(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 6, sh.getLastRow(),1))]);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

  if (protection.canDomainEdit()){
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

I have a range of cells, all protected except for F2: F.  This code runs fine and it will automatically protect all `Sheet0` except the last line onwards.  But what I really need is that it just needs to enable protection for cells already entered with the content `OK`(F), the blank and false cells will still be editable.  How do I need to edit it to make it work as I please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to protect the cells of the column "F", only when the cell value is `OK`.

In this case, as a simple modification, how about the following modification of your script?

#### From:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges([(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 6, sh.getLastRow(),1))]);
```

#### To:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll());
```

- In this modification, the cells except for the cells which have the value of OK`are retrieved using TextFinder and the retrieved ranges are set for`setUnprotectedRanges`.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: @Leti Now, I modified the regex. Could you please confirm it? But, if I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: And now it's very slow my phone has stopped working, hh. It is possible that it has to find ```OK``` in the whole range of cells F causing lag. Is there any way it just looks within A: G available.

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. But I would like to support you. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thank u replying, I have poor English skill too hi. I have 1 new question here. it will solve the above problem, can you help me pls :D [Protect specified range in google Sheet with GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134435/protect-specified-range-in-google-sheet-with-gas)

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I could confirm your new question. From it, I thought that I might be able to understand your new question. So I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.