# Protect specified range in google Sheet with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function Lock(){

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName('6');
  var protection = sh.protect().setDescription('BVDATA');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll());
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

  if (protection.canDomainEdit()){
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

@Tanaike guided me to this. Now i have a problem, that code will automatically protect 1 cell F if it value is `OK`. Is there a way for me it will protect `F:G`(like `F5:G5` will be protected if `F5` value `OK`) if F has a value of `OK`?. I tried modification :

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:G").CreateTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").MatchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll());
```

but it only protects cell G when the value is `OK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to protect the cells of the columns "F" and "G", only when the cell value is `OK`.

In order to achieve this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll());
```

#### To:

```
protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));
```

- In this modification, the searched range is expanded using `offset`.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: It nice, that exactly what i want, thank you so much :))

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike. I have a new question can you take a look at for me pls? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394057/how-to-add-value-in-a-separate-cell-for-google-forms-that-get-new-responses-ever?noredirect=1#comment119126384_67394057

Comment: @Leti About your new question of your comment, I will check it. When I could correctly understand about your new question, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: I just added a video on Youtube to describe it, you can watch it kk.

Comment: hi. ```protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("F1:F").createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, 0, 1, 2)));``` , how to select both ```OK``` and ```False``` will protect the cell range. I have try change ```||``` but not work.

Comment: @Leti About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your comment, I cannot understand your new question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: ```createTextFinder("^(?!OK).*$")``` sorry ,Currently, code find text OK and protects the cell. I need to  protect cell if text is  ```OK``` OR ```False```, how do I correct it: D

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. From your replying, I cannot still understand about your new question.  I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. For example, by including the sample situation, can you post it as new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it. And also, in that case, the users including me can also think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: hihi. Your quotes : 


I believe your goal as follows.

You want to protect the cells of the columns "F" and "G", only when the cell value is OK. Now i want to protect the cells of the columns "F" and "G",  when the cell value is ```OK``` or ```False```.

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `hihi. Your quotes :`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?