# How to add value in a separate cell for Google Forms that get new responses every day? Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I have 1 spreadsheet consisting of many sheets (Z, Y, C ....).
- Each worksheet is a sample answer of each salesperson
- They will be divided by a percentage for each customer
- when they meet the target, they will be raised the percentage of sales and this percentage due to  I decide and add it directly in the sheet.  It's still done manually and sometimes wrong.
- The answer of the form is 3 columns (A, B, C) and I will add a Profit Sharing to column D.
- So I think I will create a new sheet with column A as the names of the sheets,  B is Profit.  Share (%) as shown in the picture.
- Once the response has been added to the form, the application script will automatically add to column D of that percentage of sheets equal to the current number in the Profit Sharing column.
- And when Profit Sharing changes, following responses will be affected without changing previously existing ones.

[image: column B values ​​will be added to the worksheet in column A]

[image: when someone adds a form response]

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet with the questions?

Comment: I just added a video on Youtube to describe it :D

Comment: @Aerials can you help me pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve your desired result by using the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function.

#### For example:

In the sheet named: "Nhân viên A" you would write query the formula as:

> `QUERY('Tổng hợp'!A2:B;"select B where A = 'Nhân viên A'";-1)`

This will give you the percentage in column B of "Tổng hợp" sheet that corresponds to "Nhân viên A".

Furthermore, we can add it as an `ARRAYFORMULA` so that it is expanded automatically, for this we should use an `IF` conditional as well.

To finish, you should got to every form response sheet and add the following formula in cell `D2`

> `=ArrayFormula(SI(A2:A <> "";query('Tổng hợp'!A2:B;"select B where A = 'Nhân viên A'";-1);""))`

where you should **substitute "Nhân viên A" for the name of each response sheet.**

---

See the result in the screenshot:[image]

---

#### UPDATE:

To bake the percentage listed in "Tổng hợp" at the time of form submission(s) you should create a trigger for each form using its Id. And have it trigger a function which reads the percentage and puts it into the last row entered that corresponds to that form's response sheet.

For this you should use a script as follows:

1. From your sheet create a script using Tools > Script Editor
2. Write a function like the following for the "Nhân viên A" form:

```js
function bakePercentageA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Where is the percentage range?
  var range = "B2";
  // Get the corresponding percentage value
  var percentage = ss.getSheetByName("Tổng hợp").getRange(range).getValue();
  
  // Get the range to put the percentage value in
  var clientSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Nhân viên A");
  var lastRow = clientSheet.getLastRow();

  // Bake the value into the range
  clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(percentage);
}
```

3. Create a trigger for the form "Nhân viên A" which triggers the previous function by running once a function like the following:

```js
function createTriggers() {
  var formA = FormApp.openById('<Nhân viên A form Id>');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('bakePercentageA')
    .forForm(formA)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

4. Repeat the steps for each of your forms.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using query will change the previous percentage. for example the first 5 customers the percentage is ```50%```, to the 6th customer onwards the percentage is ```90%``` (I will change the percentage in the "Tổng hợp" sheet ), I think this can only be done with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Oh, I understand, you want to bake into the row; the percentage that is listed at the time of form response submission?

Comment: Yes!!. Thanks for replying. ```createTriggers()``` works great every time I submit the form, but I don't know where I went wrong, ```bakePercentageA()``` doesn't set value to sheet 'Nhân viên A'. I do it directly on that spreadsheet, you can check it out in Apps Script.

Comment: I just tested it, and the value is set to the sheet for every new form submission

Comment: Hi @Aerials. There is a problem that sometimes Google Apps Script will crash, and maybe there will be 1 blank cell, can i edit it so it will set value to last cell and previous empty cells.